# How to get rid of 'key not found: source' error and blocking deploying in Play framework 2.4.4

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework-2.4

In the play 2.4.4 framework I get at a seemingly random time the error 'key not found: SOURCE' at deployment time. After this happens once there is no way to use that development environment again. I have to go back to a previously saved version of the project and try again. If I make the same code changes (for example something simple like extend a table in a Play HTML page) the same might happen or not. (I use Intellij Idea version 15 Ultimate)
After some research this error message seems to have to do with the generation of the *.template.scala file for the html pages of the play framework.
Suggested older remedies talk about using the the 'play clean update' command but nowadays there seems to be only the Activate and I have not found a way to let id do cleaning and updating.
Any idea of why this is happening almost every 2 or 3 deployments ? What can I do to reset the situation ? Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Stack dump follows for information:

```
--- (Running the application, auto-reloading is enabled) ---

[info] p.c.s.NettyServer - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000

Server started, use Alt+D to stop

[info] Compiling 39 Scala sources and 1 Java source to E:\source\scalaIntelliJ\auctioneer\target\scala-2.11\classes...
java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: SOURCE
    at scala.collection.MapLike$class.default(MapLike.scala:228)
    at scala.collection.AbstractMap.default(Map.scala:58)
    at scala.collection.MapLike$class.apply(MapLike.scala:141)
    at scala.collection.AbstractMap.apply(Map.scala:58)
    at play.twirl.compiler.GeneratedSource.source(TwirlCompiler.scala:129)
    at play.twirl.compiler.GeneratedSource.sync(TwirlCompiler.scala:138)
    at play.twirl.sbt.TemplateCompiler$$anonfun$syncGenerated$2.apply(TemplateCompiler.scala:38)
    at play.twirl.sbt.TemplateCompiler$$anonfun$syncGenerated$2.apply(TemplateCompiler.scala:38)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at play.twirl.sbt.TemplateCompiler$.syncGenerated(TemplateCompiler.scala:38)
    at play.twirl.sbt.TemplateCompiler$.compile(TemplateCompiler.scala:23)
    at play.twirl.sbt.SbtTwirl$$anonfun$compileTemplatesTask$1.apply(SbtTwirl.scala:87)
    at play.twirl.sbt.SbtTwirl$$anonfun$compileTemplatesTask$1.apply(SbtTwirl.scala:86)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
    at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:63)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
    at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:235)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
    at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:159)
    at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] (compile:twirlCompileTemplates) java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: SOURCE
[error] application - 

! @6po0l44eg - Internal server error, for (GET) [/] ->

play.sbt.PlayExceptions$UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception[NoSuchElementException: key not found: SOURCE]
    at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$$anonfun$taskFailureHandler$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:51) ~[na:na]
    at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$$anonfun$taskFailureHandler$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:44) ~[na:na]
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) ~[scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$.taskFailureHandler(PlayReload.scala:44) ~[na:na]
    at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$.compileFailure(PlayReload.scala:40) ~[na:na]
    at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$$anonfun$compile$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(PlayReload.scala:20) ~[na:na]
    at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$$anonfun$compile$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(PlayReload.scala:20) ~[na:na]
    at scala.util.Either$LeftProjection.map(Either.scala:377) ~[scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$$anonfun$compile$2.apply(PlayReload.scala:20) ~[na:na]
    at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$$anonfun$compile$2.apply(PlayReload.scala:18) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: SOURCE
    at scala.collection.MapLike$class.default(MapLike.scala:228) ~[scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.collection.AbstractMap.default(Map.scala:58) ~[scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.collection.MapLike$class.apply(MapLike.scala:141) ~[scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.collection.AbstractMap.apply(Map.scala:58) ~[scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at play.twirl.compiler.GeneratedSource.source(TwirlCompiler.scala:129) ~[na:na]
    at play.twirl.compiler.GeneratedSource.sync(TwirlCompiler.scala:138) ~[na:na]
    at play.twirl.sbt.TemplateCompiler$$anonfun$syncGenerated$2.apply(TemplateCompiler.scala:38) ~[na:na]
    at play.twirl.sbt.TemplateCompiler$$anonfun$syncGenerated$2.apply(TemplateCompiler.scala:38) ~[na:na]
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59) ~[scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47) ~[scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. In addition to providing your stack trace, please also include the code for the problem area.

Comment: Hi Buczek, thank you for your reply.

Comment: Hi Buczek, thank you for your reply. The error message I got was about meta information that gets generated at the end of the *.template.scala files by the Play template compiler. It looks for a specially formatted comment that contains fields like 'SOURCE'. This comment starts with the pattern '-- GENERATED --'. I was generating source files usingmy own code generator. I also generated the '<!-- GENERATED -->' in my code. This conflicted 'sometimes' with the meta information in the *.template.scala files. Took some long days, man ! Kind regards, Rob